# Conditional probability thoughts

Tags: probability

here's a simple question

> There are ten families in a village. Two without kids, one with one
>   kids, five with two kids and two with 3 kids. I randomly knock on a
>   door. A kid opens the door and says he lives there. What is the
>   probability that he's the only one?

So, there are 8 families with kids, one of them only has one kid. Its easy to see that the answer is $\frac{1}{8}$. How do I define two events $A,B$ such that $P(A|B)=\frac{1}{8}$?

At first I thought about 
$$A_i=\{I\, picked\, a\, house\, with\, i\, kids\}$$
$$B=\{I\, picked\, a\, house\, with\, at\, least\, one\, kid\}$$
but then what is $P(A_1|B)$? To me it seems that $P(A_1\cap B)=\frac{1}{8}$ and $P(B)=\frac{4}{5}$ which means that $P(A_1|B)=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{5}{4}$

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: If you pick a house where a kid lives, what is the probability that the kid (rather than one of his parents) opens the door? Without some assumption about that I don't think you can reach a definite answer.

Comment: And are kids who have siblings more likely to be at home when you come knocking, because they don't need to leave the house in order to find someone to play with?

Comment: These are all important questions :) but I've got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_1\subset B$, $P(A_1\cap B)=P(A_1)=\frac1{10}$. The rest is correct.